# How to use panda's to_xml with multiple root name?

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I am writing to xml using to_xml as bellow :-

```py
df.to_xml(
    os.path.join(file_path, f"{os.path.basename(file)}"),
    index=False,
    root_name="GenevaLoader",
    namespaces=namespaces,
    row_name="Expenses_New",
    xml_declaration=False,
)
```

I am getting this:

```xml
<GenevaLoader xmlns:GenevaLoader="blahh" xmlns:xsi="blahh" xmlns="" >
<Expenses_New>
<Comments>AAA</Comments>
<Portfolio>BBB</Portfolio>
<NetCounterAmount>1</NetCounterAmount>
</Expenses_New>
<Expenses_New>
<Comments>AAA</Comments>
<Portfolio>XXX</Portfolio>
<NetCounterAmount>2</NetCounterAmount>
</Expenses_New>
<Expenses_New>
<Comments>CCC</Comments>
<Portfolio>ZZZ</Portfolio>
<NetCounterAmount>3</NetCounterAmount>
</Expenses_New>
</GenevaLoader>
```

Basically, I want to add a TransactionRecord tag around all the Expenses_New tags which is my row_name but bellow my root name root_name='GenevaLoader'

```xml
<GenevaLoader xmlns:GenevaLoader="blahh" xmlns:xsi="blahh"  xmlns="">
<TransactionRecords>
<Expenses_New>
<Comments>AAA</Comments>
<Portfolio>BBB</Portfolio>
<NetCounterAmount>1</NetCounterAmount>
</Expenses_New>
<Expenses_New>
<Comments>AAA</Comments>
<Portfolio>XXX</Portfolio>
<NetCounterAmount>2</NetCounterAmount>
</Expenses_New>
<Expenses_New>
<Comments>CCC</Comments>
<Portfolio>ZZZ</Portfolio>
<NetCounterAmount>3</NetCounterAmount>
</Expenses_New>
</TransactionRecords>
</GenevaLoader>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading through the source code for both supported builders, It does not seem [`to_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html) supports this behaviour. The root must be a string, the immediate next step is creating elements from the rows. There is no code in between for which to add a sub-element in this location. `to_xml` is _very_ new (1.3.0)  so its features are a bit lacking. You may have to implement this yourself using `lxml` directly.

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker, I know this is an older post but a newer question linked to this one. You can edit the XML in *any* style using XSLT. The `stylesheet` argument has been available for `to_xml` since v1.3.0!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @HenryEcker in a comment, the best way to manipulate xml is with an xml parser:

```
from lxml import etree
load = """your output xml above"""
doc = etree.XML(load.encode())

#this is one way of approaching the namespaces issue:
targets = doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="Expenses_New"]')
etree.SubElement(doc, 'TransactionRecords')
destination = doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="TransactionRecords"]')[0]
for target in targets:
    destination.append(target)
destination.tail = "  \n"
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<GenevaLoader xmlns:GenevaLoader="blahh" xmlns:xsi="blahh">
   <TransactionRecords><Expenses_New>
      <Comments>AAA</Comments>
      <Portfolio>BBB</Portfolio>
      <NetCounterAmount>1</NetCounterAmount>
   </Expenses_New>
   <Expenses_New>
      <Comments>AAA</Comments>
      <Portfolio>XXX</Portfolio>
      <NetCounterAmount>2</NetCounterAmount>
   </Expenses_New>
   <Expenses_New>
      <Comments>CCC</Comments>
      <Portfolio>ZZZ</Portfolio>
      <NetCounterAmount>3</NetCounterAmount>
   </Expenses_New>
</TransactionRecords>  
</GenevaLoader>
```

Comment: thanks a lot this works just changes the logic a bit use parse instead of XML as I am reading from xml file

Answer (score 0):

Pandas XML IO does support XSLT 1.0 (the special-purpose language to transform XML files) for `to_xml`. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-xml) using the `stylesheet` argument which is only support by the default `lxml` parser (which you do use).

Below XSLT runs the identity transform to copy document as is then re-styles the `<GenevaLoader>` node to add a child, `<TransactionRecords>`, element. Not quite sure what you intended for defualt namespace so below uses `https://example.com` as URI.

```py
strXSLT = """\
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="https://example.com"> 
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="doc:GenevaLoader">
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:element name="TransactionRecords" namespace="https://example.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>"""

df.to_xml(
    'test.xml', 
    index = False, 
    root_name = "GenevaLoader", 
    namespaces = {"": "http://example.com", "GenevaLoader": "blahh", "xsi": "blahh"},
    row_name = "Expenses_New", 
    xml_declaration = False,
    stylesheet = strXSLT
)
```