# How to add a root inside of main root of XML in Pyton

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml which i have export using the following:

```
df.to_xml('test.xml', index=False, row_name='instance', root_name='file')
```

which produces an xml file like:

```
<file>
  <instance>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>32</age>
    <city>London</city>
  </instance>
....
</file>
```

How can i add an extra root (`<NAMES>`) for underneath `<file>` so my output is below:

```
<file>
<NAMES>
  <instance>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>32</age>
    <city>London</city>
  </instance>
....
</NAMES>
</file>
```

Comment: There is an example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68551975/how-to-use-pandas-to-xml-with-multiple-root-name it seems like it is not supported with pandas so you will have to edit your XML using XML parsing library like lxml

Comment: @NivDadush, you can edit the document with XSLT. See `stylesheet` argument of `to_xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'Files' as subelement to the root and to save it you can use standard file object.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(df.to_xml(index=False, row_name='instance', root_name='file'))
file = ET.Element("file")
files = ET.SubElement(file, 'Files')
for e in root:
  files.append(e)
f = open('test.xml','w')
f.write(ET.tostring(file))
```

Comment: Thanks @Surjut Samra, do you know how to then save this to file?

Comment: updated , you can use standard file object

Comment: Thanks @Surjit Samra when i run it, i can see that the `<Files>` has a space and forward slash in it?
Start of XML:`<file>
  <Files /><instance>
    <ID>1</ID>`

End of file:  `  </instance>
<Files /></file>`

Comment: i was hoping for it to say `<Files>` at the start and then `</Files> at the end`

Comment: ok , this should do it

Answer (score 3):

Pandas XML IO does support XSLT 1.0 (the special-purpose language to transform XML files) for `to_xml`. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-xml) using the `stylesheet` argument which is only support by the default `lxml` parser (which you do use).

Below XSLT runs the identity transform to copy document as is then re-styles the `<file>` node to add a child `<NAMES>` element:

```py
strXSLT = """\
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:copy> 
      <NAMES>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
      </NAMES>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>"""

df.to_xml(
    'test.xml', 
    index = False, 
    row_name = 'instance', 
    root_name = 'file',
    stylesheet = strXSLT
)
```

Comment: For huge files this is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

As an option to the above solution, without`for` looping over the whole list:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

source = """<file>
  <instance>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>32</age>
    <city>London</city>
  </instance>
  <instance />
</file>"""

f = StringIO(source)

#### you can read your file f here ####
tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()

#### modification, new root and rename old root ####
new_root = ET.Element('file')
root.find('.').tag = "NAMES"
new_root.append(root)

#### pretty print ####
root = ET.ElementTree(new_root)
ET.indent(root, space="  ")
# root.write("test.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8", )
ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<file>
  <NAMES>
    <instance>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <name>John</name>
      <age>32</age>
      <city>London</city>
    </instance>
    <instance />
  </NAMES>
</file>
```